# Php blob image display on modal popup using JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I've been trying to call a modal pop up

```
<div class="image content">
    <div class="ui medium image">
      <img style="max-width:400px;" src="" id="imgretprd">
      <br/>
      <div class="ui tiny images" style="width:500px;" align="left">
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Now in my html

```
<img id="imgretprdlist{{$product->productId}}" src="data:image/png;base64,{{base64_encode($image_prod->Blob1)}}"/>
```

I wanted to call the image that is retrieved here on the modal pop up above on my click function.

I tried using this code

```
  var ret_prodImg = document.getElementById('imgretprd');
    ret_prodImg = document.getElementById('imgretprdlist'+id).src;
```

But that's not working. It shows me blank only. Where am I going wrong?

Any answers to this will be appreciated.

Comment: What is expected value of `Blob1`?

Comment: atleast it shows me image on the main page... and its base_64 encoded string.

Comment: Is `Blob1` a `base64` encoded string?

Comment: yes. `blob1` is `base64`

Comment: Is the image displayed at `<img>` element? What is expected result of `ret_prodImg = document.getElementById('imgretprdlist'+id).src;`? What is value of `ret_prodImg`?